# Dot operator on pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Lets say that I have a struct

```
typedef struct list_entry {
    int val;
    int val2;
} list_entry;
```

and a pointer to it

```
list_entry list;
list_entry* pList = &list;
```

Then how come that `(*pList).val2` gives me the value stored at `list.val2` if `*pList` returns the value at address stored in `pList` and since `pList` holds the address of list, `*pList` should return the number stored in val? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  The will get into great detail on how pointers work and what it means to dereference one.

Comment: For the same reason `list.val2` gives you the value at `val2` and not at `val`. You simply access an attribute of a compound data type.

Comment: You're accessing `val2`, so you get the value stored in `val2`. How is that surprising, and why would you expect to end up with `val` instead?

Comment: Completely normal you are asking for member `val2` you are getting `val2` . However  `*((int*)pList)` is `val`

Comment: +1 to @NathanOliver reply. You are probably confusing the * operator and * declarator, or, in other words, when * is used to declare a pointer and when * is used to **dereference** a pointer.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume for the sake of the argument that `int` is 4 bytes. Now `list_entry` is at least 8 bytes. Yet `pList` only points to the first of those 8 bytes.

Now how can all these expressions work? In C (and C++ for that matter), the compiler looks at the whole expression. The `.val2` member is probably a 4 byte value, at byte offsets 4-7. Don't worry about the exact details, that's the compilers job. If you insert a member between `val` and `val2`,  everything will move but the compiler still keeps track.

So in `(*pList).val2`, the compiler knows to add 4 bytes to `pList` and then take the next 4 bytes.

Note that the compiler is generally helpful with this sort of math. `pList+1` does not add 1 byte, but `1 * sizeof(list_entry)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. `*pList` should give you the value at address stored in `pList`. But the type of value is `list_entry`. `*pList` gave you back a value of type `list_entry` and `(*pList).val2` is `val2` field in that `list_entry`.

Now, if you read value at `*pList` as an `int` then you will get value of field `val`.
e.g. `*((int*)pList)`
TLDR: `*pList` does return the value at address stored in `pList` but the type of value is decided by the type of `*pList`.